# Props passed from Parent to Child component is undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass a boolean value from Parent to Child through a props.
in the **Parent component:**

```js
class Parent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }
        ...
        render() {
          ...
          retrun (
          <Child
            addSearchBar
            value="child 1"
          />
          <Child
            value="child 2"
          />
          );
        }
    }
```

I tried to do this `addSearchbar={true}` but i got an `ESLint` error `ESLint: Value must be omitted for boolean attributes`.
And in the **Child component** when i'm trying `console.log` the props `addSearchbar` isn't within the props it has a value of `undefined`. How can i pass the boolean value?

```js
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props) <-- addSearchbar isn't within the props

      this.state = {
        searchText: '',
      };
    }
    ...
    render() {
      const {
        addSearchbar
      } = this.props;
      
      console.log(addSearchbar) <--undefined
      
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For boolean props, you don't have to provide a value.

If you don't pass the prop, the value will be false

```
<Child/>
```

If you  pass the prop, the value will be true

```
<Child addSearchbar/>
```

I created a basic [working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/sanjar/pen/KKaeEpr?editors=0111)

Comment: I did the same thing.. but i don't know why `addSearchbar` doesn't figure out with the rest of the props when i try to console.log the props of the child component

Comment: Ok, can you provide the code you're using to render the Child component?

Comment: i posted the Child component

Comment: Can you also add the code used to call this component? (sorry if it wasn't clear)